# How to store all the UIFont size value's into NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Does we can store all the UIFontSize into mutableArray.

Example

We can store all the font family into mutable array like this

```
_familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];
    NSInteger indFamily;
    for (indFamily=0; indFamily<[_familyNames count]; ++indFamily)
    {
        [_familyNames objectAtIndex:indFamily];

    }
```

In this same passion can we store the UIFont size into mutableArray..

Is it possible.

Answer (score 2):

No because there is an unlimited number of font sizes. Note that fontWithSize takes a float:

```
- (UIFont *)fontWithSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
```

Fonts are simply specified at what ever size is needed.  One can create an array of NSNumbers of preferred font sizes to present as many applications do.